# Odoo 16: Playing with translations and Boom ! No longer can access my custom model data in my server

Tags: postgresql, odoo, translation, odoo-16

After successfully adding a pot file to my new i18n folder in my local machine, as well as setting "translate=True" in a couple of fields in my carddecks module, and verifying that in localhost I could acess my model data, I decided to update my server.
But when I try to access my model data I get the following error:

```
LINE 1: ..."write_date", COALESCE("carddecks_card"."cardText"->>'pt_PT'...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Anyone might know what may be causing this?

source code for the module can be found at https://github.com/diogocsc/carddecks

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1579, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/model.py", line 134, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1608, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1805, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 235, in _dispatch
    response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 144, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 698, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 42, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 457, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/api.py", line 430, in _call_kw_model
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/models/models.py", line 62, in web_search_read
    records = self.search_read(domain, fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 4968, in search_read
    result = records.read(fields, **read_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 2992, in read
    self._read(stored_fields)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 3235, in _read
    cr.execute(query_str, params + [sub_ids])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/sql_db.py", line 315, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: character varying ->> unknown
LINE 1: ..."write_date", COALESCE("carddecks_card"."cardText"->>'pt_PT'...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


The above server error caused the following client error:
OwlError: The following error occurred in onWillStart: "Odoo Server Error"
    at wrapError (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/504-41b52e3/web.assets_common.min.js:1445:77)
    at onWillStart (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/504-41b52e3/web.assets_common.min.js:1451:117)
    at useModel (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/505-11285c6/web.assets_backend.min.js:4709:1)
    at ListController.setup (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/505-11285c6/web.assets_backend.min.js:4430:645)
    at new ComponentNode (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/504-41b52e3/web.assets_common.min.js:1407:136)
    at https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/504-41b52e3/web.assets_common.min.js:1929:6
    at View.slot1 (eval at compile (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/504-41b52e3/web.assets_common.min.js:1892:370), <anonymous>:15:36)
    at callSlot (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/504-41b52e3/web.assets_common.min.js:1508:25)
    at WithSearch.template (eval at compile (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/504-41b52e3/web.assets_common.min.js:1892:370), <anonymous>:8:12)
    at Fiber._render (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/504-41b52e3/web.assets_common.min.js:1336:96)

Caused by: RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    at makeErrorFromResponse (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/505-11285c6/web.assets_backend.min.js:967:163)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://www.relationalgames.com/web/assets/505-11285c6/web.assets_backend.min.js:974:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for this. In my localhost I was updating my module. In my server i was just running docker-compose up. Not updating the module in the db.

The solution was going to settings -> apps search by cardecks and upgrade it.